# HP-UX Java Configuration issue

Tags: java, unix

I have a JAVA program compiled with JDK 1.5. I tested it on Windows (7 and XP), it is working fine. But when this program deployed to HPUX server it gives following error:

```
nested exception is: 
HTTP transport error: javax.xml.soap.SOAPException: java.security.PrivilegedActionException: javax.xml.soap.SOAPException: Message send failed: String index out of range: -7
```

I have changed the java.policy file with policytool and give allpermission but still getting same error.
Then I read somewhere that put java.policy file to local home of the user as named policy file like ".java.policy" but it also gives the same error.

Finally I tested it with a signed JAR but that returns NULL object. Also signed jar does not work on Windows

Comment: Could you publish full stack trace? What does `java -version` produce on HP-UX?

Comment: Here is printed version of JAVA: java version "1.5.0.09"
Java(TM) 2 Runtime Environment, Standard Edition (build 1.5.0.09-_18_aug_2007_07_52)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 1.5.0.09 jinteg:08.18.07-13:19 IA64, mixed mode)